# PHP8 ?-> in IF statements

Tags: if-statement, conditional-operator, php-8

In the old PHP, IF statements were written as

```
if ($a && $a->b()) {
    ...
}
```

Can the above be written in PHP8 as

```
if ($a?->b()) {
    ...
}
```

Can a class method be used simply (without equation) as

```
$a?->b();
```

instead of

```
if ($a) {
    $a->b();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two statements are not *technically* equivalent, but *may* be what was intended.

The `?->` operator is called [the nullsafe operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.nullsafe), and is specifically checking the left-hand side for **null**. As that manual page says:

> The effect is similar to wrapping each access in an is_null() check first, but more compact.

So the following are all equivalent

```
if (is_null($a) && $a->b()) {
    echo 'here';
}

if ($a === null && $a->b()) {
    echo 'here';
}

if ($a?->b()) {
    echo 'here';
}
```

However, that's not *quite* what you wrote; you used `$a` by itself "in boolean context", meaning all you were checking for was that it was "truthy" or "not empty". To demonstrate, consider this:

```
$a = false;
if ($a && $a->b()) {
    echo 'here';
}
```

Here the existing code will shortcut, but a nullsafe operator would not. A fully verbose version of the intention might look like this:

```
$a = true;
if ($a instanceof SomeClass && $a->b()) {
    echo 'here';
}
```

In practice, you *probably* already know that `$a` is either the correct object or null (e.g. it's passed a `?SomeClass` type constraint on a parameter or property), in which case yes, the `?->` nullsafe operator means you no longer need the extra check.